# How to get the yyyyDDmm000 date format in impala shell?

Tags: date, date-format, impala

I want to use the `yyyyDDmm000` date format in impala-shell. 
Example: **20221122000**

I have used the below query.
`select from_timestamp(date_sub(now(), 1), 'yyyyMMdd');` 
And the result was **20221121**. 
And When I used the below query I got **WARNINGS: Bad date/time conversion format: yyyyMMdd000**. 
`select from_timestamp(date_sub(now(), 1), 'yyyyMMdd000');` 
How can we achieve this format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the desired output.
I have used below query to get this date format.
`select CAST(concat(from_timestamp((now()-interval 1 day), 'yyyyMMdd'),'000') AS BIGINT);`